# Same host, same python sys.path output, different import results

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

How is this possible? [Same Host, 2 terminal windows with different python import results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40oha.png)

I validated that $PYTHONPATH is the same in both terminal windows. I am positive that both the left and right pane are the same host machine. I just manually installed the `macholib` module in the right terminal window with `sudo -H python3 setup.py install` under the root folder. This server does not have internet connectivity hence why I need to manually scp the compressed zip packages and install manually without pip.

EDIT: I have closed terminals and reopened them and found that the package needed to be re-installed each time.

Comment: What is `macholib.__file__` in the right window?

Comment: `/home/user/macholib-1.16.2/macholib/__init__.py`